# vlookup get latest match of duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to display a filtered version of sheet1 data in sheet2:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

I used vlookup on sheet2 columns C,D,E to display sheet1 columns B,D,A respectively.

**i.e., Sheet 2 - Column C**

```
=vlookup(A2,Sheet1!A3:D,3)
```

but I'm not sure how to make it work with duplicates and to only get the latest one.
I tried using vlookup on query result but it didn't work out (because I was referencing a reference?)

```
=sortn(query(Sheet1!A2:D6,"select * where A is not null order by B,A desc"),99^99, 2, 2, true)
```

How can I apply vlookup to get the latest match of duplicate rows? If it's not possible, how can I go about this (if possible, without having to add extra sheets)

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to use Vlookup and Query to do it, I would end up with something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(query(B2:B,"select min(B) where B is not null group by B label min(B) ''"),
query(A2:D,"select B,A,C+D,C,D where A is not null order by B,A"),{2,1,3,4,5}))
```

so the first query gets the unique values of column B, and the second query gets the original data plus total (C+D) sorted in ascending order of family name then timestamp. Then vlookup finds the *last* matching value for each family name, which in this case is the latest one. You could also sort on timestamp descending and use the exact form of vlookup to find the *first* occurrence - probably a little bit slower:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(query(B2:B,"select min(B) where B is not null group by B label min(B) ''"),
query(A2:D,"select B,A,C+D,C,D where A is not null order by B,A desc"),{2,1,3,4,5},0))
```

In reality I would probably use sort and sortn as I think you started to do in your question:

```
=sortn(sort(filter({A2:B,C2:C+D2:D,C2:D},A2:A<>""),2,1,1,0),999,2,2,1)
```

This time it's sorted on family name ascending then timestamp descending, then sortn removes duplicates.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(Sheet1!A:D, ROW(Sheet1!A:D), 0), 3, 0)))
```